# Using an enum before it's declared

Tags: c++, enums

I have a C++ header file with an enum declared in the public section:

```
enum Button {A, B, C, D};
```

And a map, using that enum as a template parameter in the private section:

```
map<Button, int> bindings;
```

This would work perfectly if it weren't because I like to define the private section before the public one, so the compiler doesn't recognise Button as a symbol. I've checked and moving Button declaration before the map declaration works.

This seems like a huge limitation to me, is there a workaround I can use without having to flip the public and private sections of my header file?

Comment: "Huge limitation"? Oh come on.

Comment: If I want to be consistent and make my header files look alike I should be able to define my public and private sections in any particular order I like. If by your sarcastic comment you mean there is no way to do what I'm asking this please state this as a proper answer.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean, and I am trying to think of a useful answer, I just mean that even if it's impossible, it would be a fairly minor limitation.

Comment: It's really not a huge limitation at all by any objective criteria. When someone reads the documentation of your class, the order in which declarations appear in the header file does not matter. The header file itself should not be the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can in C++11.

You cannot just forward-declare enumerations because the compiler needs to know the size of the enumeration before you can use it and the size of the enumeration depends on the amount and value of elements in it.

C++11 adds new syntax which allows you to tell the compiler the size of the enumeration:

```
enum <name> : <underlying_type>
```

So you can write your class as:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    enum Button : char;
private:
    map<Button, int> bindings;
public:
    enum Button : char
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    };
};
```

You still cannot get the forward-declaration out of the public section, though. But the definition can come after the map declaration.

Comment: Thank you for not only making clear the how but also the why. +1 For that. I'll accept this when time limit is over.

Comment: The rationale here, about knowing the `enum` size, seems a bit suspect. Are you sure that a forward declaration of an `enum class` won't work? If that's supported, as my testing with visual c++ and g++ indicates, then the unknown size is not a problem (maybe a default large size is assumed, or maybe size `int` is assumed and any larger named value is then an error, whatever).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf You guessed it already, but it's in C++11 7.2p5 "The underlying type can be explicitly specified using *enum-base*; if not explicitly specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is `int`."

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions (both require C++11):

```
class S {
public:
    enum class Button;
private:
    std::map<Button, int> bindings;
public:
    enum class Button {A, B, C, D};
};
```

Or:

```
class S {
public:
    enum Button : int;
private:
    std::map<Button, int> bindings;
public:
    enum Button : int {A, B, C, D};
};
```

Comment: +1 this sounds about right. although some standard's quotes would be nice. especially for the `enum class` case.

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum class or specify a default type for your enum, then you can forward declare it.

E.g:

```
enum class Button;
```

But still, this forward declaration must be in a private section.

Btw: `private` before `public` is quite strange. Shouldn't the public interface that others are to use be at the top?

Comment: `private` before `public` is not a bit stranger than the opposite. Both styles are widely used. Besides, there are two kinds of "others". The *clients* of the class and the *implementors* (if it's an OOP base class). The implementors are interested in the virtual functions of the class, and virtual functions are preferably `private`, not `public`. So which party is more important?

Comment: FWIW, have a look at http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#friend and you'll see an example where Stroustrup himself uses private before public.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think this is probably a bad idea, here's one way to do this that actually really does avoid even a forward-declaration of any of the public members of your class:

```
class MyClass;
class MyClassPublic;
template <typename> class MyClassPrivate;

template <typename TPublic = MyClassPublic>
class MyClassPrivate : public TPublic
{
    map<typename TPublic::Button, int> bindings;
};

class MyClassPublic
{
public:
    enum Button { A, B, C, D };
};

class MyClass : public MyClassPrivate<>
{
};
```

It relies on the fact that template classes are processed in two stages, once at template definition time, and once at template instantiation time. At template definition time, some references to not-yet-defined members are permitted.